# Trouble connecting to localhost from browser using WSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fastapi, wsl-2

I am trying to develop a Python FastAPI endpoint on Windows in a Ubuntu WSL environment but seem to be unable to view/access this from my browser. The weird thing is that I tried this a few days ago and it seemed to work fine but hasn't worked since as I seem to get this error from using curl in my powershell:

```
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

And in any browser I get an error where it can't find that server.

Here's some example code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {
        "message": "Hello World"
    }
```

and then I run `uvicorn main:app --reload` to start the app and try to access the endpoint provided.

My OS build version is 19041.508 if that matters.

Does anyone know how I can get this working again? I have no idea what could be going wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: To note, if I run curl within wsl for that endpoint, I get the expected response.
Secondly, I've also tried to access from the browser using the IP address for the wsl virtualmachine which also gave the same error

Comment: Have you tried running the app via uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 main:app --reload ?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and get the same error. Firefox says "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 0.0.0.0:8000" and curl from outside the wsl still gives the same error too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone sees this in the future, I ended up deleting and recreating the pipenv environment. This ended up getting it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the computer can sometimes fix odd connection issues.  I'm not sure why.  I was having trouble with a fastapi server refusing a secure connection, which previously worked and worked with curl but not in the browser, despite all sorts of measures.  It mysteriously would refuse any connection from a browser.  Restarted the computer and updated VS Code and everything seems to be working fine now. Maybe it was the VS Code update.

Comment: exactly this solution worked for me, the good 'ol restart.

Comment: Running `wsl --shutdown` seems to be fixing this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my machine and it works as expected. I'm running WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 on 19041.572 version of Windows 10. Use **localhost** to point to the service running as mentioned in the documentation: [WSL networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, unfortunately couldn't get it working on the existing pipenv. Ended up just deleting the existing pipenv and creating and new one which seems to be working now. Thanks for trying to help.